# How can Retrieve data in ListView from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Data Structure in Firebase]

Can you help me in this problem, I try to display data from in firebase in Listview, but Not Display anything!

```
ListView listView;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fairbase_list);

    firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference= firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");


    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    final ArrayAdapter<String>  arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this ,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    Toast.makeText(this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            arrayList.add(value);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

}

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No , but Not display any data in list

Comment: check my answer , just change activity name and layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
 ListView listView;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
     ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");


listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lists);

Toast.makeText(this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        arrayList.add(value);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

 }}
```

This listener is actually used for lists, so its not from the listener.
Also since the user is not authenticated you need to change the rules in your database to :-

```
 {
"rules": {
   ".read": "true",
   ".write": "true"
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear, that is answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the wrong listener .You should use `addValueEventListener ()` if you want to listen to changes continuously and  if you need to listen just once, you can use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`

**ValueEventListner Example**

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
PostDetailActivity.java
```

For more info , you can see this firebase sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database/PostDetailActivity.java#L84-L106)

Comment: No , the same .
Can you look database structure