# retrieve data from firebase to textview returns null how to fix?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase to a texview but it returns null, and I was wondering how I can retrieve the respective data based on the uid only of the connected user.
I tried in different ways today all afternoon but without any success, someone could help me. I've researched and tried all the stackoverflow and internet solutions as well.
I need to retrieve only the "name" field of the structure of the respective connected user.
am i doing something wrong?
any help is welcome.
I need to retrieve only the "name" field of the structure of the respective connected user.

MainActivity Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    Button btn_send;
    EditText et_contact, et_message;
    TextView textView52;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private User usuario = new User();
    private DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase;
    private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



        btn_send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
        et_contact = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_contact);
        et_message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_message);
        textView52 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView52);


        PermissionToConnect();

        btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String number = et_contact.getText().toString();
                String message = et_message.getText().toString();

                try{
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sending Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        DatabaseReference databaseRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference();

        databaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String data = dataSnapshot.child("Users").child("email").child("name").getValue(String.class);
                textView52.setText(data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

-
User Class code

```
User Class

public class User {
    public String name, email, phone;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(String name, String email, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
        databaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String data = dataSnapshot.child("Users").child("email").child("name").getValue(String.class);
                textView52.setText(data);
            }
```

Into this:

```
        databaseRef.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String data = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                textView52.setText(data);
            }
         }
```

You need to add `Users` as a reference and then iterate to get the `name` or `email`.

---

Another way if you are using firebase auth is to retrieve the current user ID thus removing the iteration.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. same problem return null :/

Comment: Works, THANKS MAN YOUR IS BEST

Comment: Hello, could you tell me what it would be like using firebase auth? Because I'm using firebase auth, sorry to bother you.

Comment: If you can help me, I would like to get the field "name" of the logged in user as I what can do this?, I would be very grateful if you can help me. I use firebase auth email / password

Comment: @GET Firebase Auth is an authentication when user logging. Firebase Realtime Database is a place we can store extra information about specific user.

Comment: Can you indicate a tutorial for me to retrieve the "name" field from the currentuser?

Comment: @GET you can search it, there are a lot of tutorials about it. If you cannot find anything, do comment here

Comment: @GET check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49463940/how-to-display-the-current-logged-in-user-firebase/49463982#49463982

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you again, I managed to authenticate the main acitivity. but I have this error if you can help me the link is this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60050114/retrieve-data-currentuser-from-firebase-return-null