# retrieve data currentuser. from firebase return null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I'm trying to retrieve the data from a realtime firebase field but it returns null. I checked with textView52.setText (firebaseUser.getEmail ()); to see if it was really connected and it works. the problem is in recovering a value from the database which in this case is the field "name" could someone help me?
am i doing something wrong?
any help is welcome.

```
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    ref.child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String userUid = user.getUid();
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String data = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            textView52.setText(data);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userUid = user.getUid();
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.child("Users").child(userUid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String data = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue();
        textView52.setText(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED! 
check those lines

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
ref.child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {...}
```

Basically you try to call in Users another child called User, to understand very easy, replace the of that user here

```
ref.child("use_that_key_here").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {...}
```

Is not a solution, you cannot hard code every key, but with this you should see the data

try something like that:

```
// ref to db
DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
ref.child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       //debug this par and check if you can see your user
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need to get it from the current user. still thanks for the help.

Comment: I understand, but you are calling "Users"->"User"->... Current user is not related to Database, let me update my answer