# display and update current user credentials with real time firebase database in xamarin forms

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a booking car app and I'm struggling with update driver car infos. I'm using a real time database with firebase and I want to display the current driver infos and give him to possibility to change his current car informations. I don't know how to display only the current logged driver infos. I read a lot of posts about the same topic but all were using auth with email. I also tried

```
await firebase.Child("Driver Vehicules").Child(auth.CurrentUser)
```

but it shows an error. How do I get only the current logged user url in Firebase? The following code display all the users, not just a single one.

```
public async Task<List<CarAndDriverDisplayInfos>> GetDriverInfos()
        {

            return (await firebase
              .Child("Driver Vehicules")
              .OnceAsync<CarAndDriverDisplayInfos>()).Select(item => new CarAndDriverDisplayInfos
              {


                  FNameDriver  = item.Object.FNameDriver,
                  LNameDriver  = item.Object.LNameDriver,
                  CTypeDriver  = item.Object.CTypeDriver,
                  CModelDriver = item.Object.CModelDriver,
                  YCarDriver = item.Object.YCarDriver,
                  ImageCarUrl  = item.Object.ImageCarUrl,
                  ImageDriverUrl = item.Object.ImageDriverUrl,
                  CarIdDriver  = item.Object.CarIdDriver,
                  PersonId = item.Object.PersonId

              }).ToList();
        } 



        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            
            base.OnAppearing();
            var Driver = await firebaseHelper.GetDriverInfos();

            lstPersons.ItemsSource = Driver;

        }
```

Comment: Hi, do you have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49463940/how-to-display-the-current-logged-in-user-firebase/49463982) to check whether it is helpful?

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT thanks to reply. No it doesn't really help me. the FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); shows me error in xamarin forms. it seams like working only for Android for what i've been reading in many other forums. my Application is for both ios and android.