# Pulling data from Firebase into an Android Application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: FireBase Image]

Above is my firebase database I am trying to pull from. 
As you can see I have a "table" called "Make". I have succesfully been able to pull this data into a Listview within my app. The code for this is below.

I now need to pull all the data from "VW_Data" table. This table has over 1000 childen named as "0" up to "1000" with the same headings in each such as "Bearing", "Altitude" etc but with different values. I would like to be able to pull "Bearing" value only from ALL 1000 children of "VW_Data" and display in a list.

However i have attempted only to try pull "VW_Data/0/Bearing" multiple ways which have not worked.

Here is my updated code for this class:

```
public class Graphview extends Activity
{
//Holds the values gathered from firebase
final ArrayList<String> graphlist = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Sets the layout according to the XML file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_graphview);

    //XML variable
    final ListView listViewG = findViewById(R.id.listviewG);


    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("VW_Data");
    database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                String bearing = (String) datas.child("Bearing").getValue();
                //Add the info retrieved from datasnapshot into the ArrayList
                graphlist.add(bearing);
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Graphview.this, R.layout.itemview, graphlist);
                listViewG.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                //Will refresh app when the data changes in the database
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}//End onCreate()
```

Comment: what did not work? Is it not retrieving anything?

Comment: @PeterHaddad none of my attempts worked for the VW_Data table. the app compiles and runs but no data is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("VW_Data");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         Iterable<DataSnapshot> verticalSnapshotItr = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

                      if (verticalSnapshotItr != null) {
                        for (DataSnapshot verticalItemSnapshot : verticalSnapshotItr) {
                     String altitude = (String) verticalItemSnapshot.child("Altitude").getValue();
             // Parse rest keys here
                }

      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
    });

}
```

Comment: On second For() getting error stating that "verticalItemSnapshot" is already define in the scope.

Comment: @ashxhj : now check

Comment: I have added my full class into my question. Please take a look and inform me of what is wrong please

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                       .getReference()
                                       .child("VW_Data");
db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String bearing = datas.child("Bearing").getValue().toString();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

snapshot is at `VW_Data` then use the for loop, you will be able to iterate inside "0" and retrieve the value `bearing`

Comment: Hi, Getting a Java null pointer exception error on the toString();

Comment: Yes, vw_data is direct child to the root node

Comment: try this: `String bearing = (String) datas.child("Bearing").getValue();`

Comment: thats compiles are runs, but how would i set it to display in Listview? like this: `graphlist.add(bearing)` I had this line inserted after and this is what was causing the error

Comment: `graphlist.add(bearing);

                        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Activity_name.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, graphlist);
                        listview.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: do you have bearing under every node under `VW_Data`?

Comment: yes, it is under every heading, some values of bearing are "0" though. but yes, it is present in every node under `VW_Data`

Comment: added breadkpoint. error coming back on `dataSnapshot: Object has been collected Cannot evaluate com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.toString() `

Comment: remove the for loop and add this in the databasereference `DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("VW_Data").child("0");` then `String bearing = dataSnaphot.child("Bearing").getValue().toString();`

Comment: this did not work, same error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999035/how-can-retrieve-data-in-listview-from-firebase

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939506/android-java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-java

Comment: change this `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to `addValueEventListener`

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: yes, i tried it. it did not work. still getting the same error

Comment: there is no hope